# Continue and pass: what's the difference?

Tags: python

What is the difference between `continue` and `pass` in Python? I am fairly new to Python and am trying to get my code looking and acting more professionally. I can see their value, but to my untrained mind, I can't see the clear difference. I have looked [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) but I couldn't really see what the main difference was. I noticed `continue` is shown in a loop example to continue to the next loop and `pass` is a 'place holder' in classes, etc.

I guess my question is, how necessary are they? Should I focus on them now to add professionalism to my code, or is it more of a take it or leave it scenario?

Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: Continue and pass do completely different things. The python official site has a great tutorial and reference for you to learn from.

Comment: Nevermind... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483979/is-there-a-different-between-continue-and-pass-in-a-for-loop-in-python?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Pass

`pass` means that you're just filling a place where a statement is usually needed

```
while True:
    pass  # The pass is needed syntactically
```

From the documentation:

> pass is a null operation -- when it is executed, nothing happens. It is useful as a placeholder when a statement is required syntactically, but no code needs to be executed, for example:

#### Continue

`continue` goes to the next iteration if any.

```
i = 1
while i<5:
    continue   # Endless loop because we're going to the next iteration
    i = i + 1
```

From the documentation:

> continue may only occur syntactically nested in a for or while loop, but not nested in a function or class definition or finally statement within that loop.6.1It continues with the next cycle of the nearest enclosing loop.

Comment: so,... it turns out that in some circumstances, they can appear to be the same.. like when they are the only thing in the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Should give me what I need. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Pass is useful for creating functions with no use. [It does absolutely nothing](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-pass-statement). I sometimes use it when starting a new project to create functions that I will use later, but I will have no need for them at the moment.

[Continue](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-continue-statement), starts a loop again with the next element in the iteration, often found after a conditional.