# Python selenium error handling

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a python selenium script that runs through a loop like this...

```
for i, refcode in enumerate(refcode_list):

    try:
        source_checkrefcode()
    except TimeoutException:
        pass
        csvWriter.writerow([refcode, 'error', timestamp])
```

If there is a problem during the source_checkrefcode then the script crashes with an error.

How can I add error handling to this loop so that it just moves to the next item instead of crashing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add a check over exception message, below is the sample code for your understanding.

```
for i, refcode in enumerate(refcode_list):
    try:
        source_checkrefcode()
    except Exception as e:
        if 'particular message' in str(e):
            # Do the following
            # if you don't want to stop for loop then just continue
            continue
```

Comment: My original code looks out for TimeoutException but your example uses Exception.  Will this new code still catch the TimeoutException as well?

Comment: Yes, Actually Exception will catch all types of exceptions. Then you can add a check on its string message. For example. If 'TimeountException' in str(e): do this elif 'Another Exception' in str(e): do this and so on

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Hassan's Answer. But if you use continue then you won't process any other block of code.

```
for i, refcode in enumerate(refcode_list):
    try:
        source_checkrefcode()
    except Exception as e:
        if 'particular message' in str(e):
            # Do the following
            # if you don't want to stop for loop then just continue
            continue
    # another code of block will skip. Use pass or continue as per your requirement.
```

You must understand the difference between pass and continue
   [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9484008/2466407)