# How to skip the while loop once in Python?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I want to skip the while loop only once. How can I do this?

```
import time
i = 0
while True:
    
    if i == 3:
        pass
    
    i += 1
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Thank you.

Comment: refer here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58872300/like-while-loops-how-can-i-skip-a-step-in-a-for-loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Like while loops, how can I skip a step in a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58872300/like-while-loops-how-can-i-skip-a-step-in-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `continue` statement to move to the beginning of the loop and that way "skip" it, but you will need to increment i first.

Comment: Is there any other way I can jump to the next iteration once a condition is satisfied?

Comment: continue is the right thing to use for skipping over a loop, a different alternative would be to wrap the internals in an if block, but that gets ugly fast, another is to use a separate function that does the work that you call for each iteration, either "return early" or use if around it.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it like this :-**

```
import time 
i = 0 
while True: 
    i += 1
    if i == 3: 
        continue   
    print(i) 
    time.sleep(1)
```